# Find out in which Slave the Jenkins Pipeline is running

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I am starting my Pipeline this way:

`node('my_Label') { // my code }`

I want to know in which Slave my code is running. I tried multiple things but I was not able to find out the correct method to call for that :(

Answer (score 10):

The environment variable ${NODE_NAME} should have it:

```
node ('my_Label) {
   println "${NODE_NAME}"
}
```

Comment: Pipeline has some restrictions on reading env variables (may need to run script outside SandBox or use a Pipeline Library)

Comment: Well, it worked fine in my instance running as part of an in-line pipeline script.